# Hide one of the October Rainlab Blog categories?

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

**How to hide** one of the **October Rainlab Blog** categories?
One of the categories should not be displayed in the Categories List on page.
I want to **use** one hidden category **only for filtering** and display special posts on HomePage.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "hide" here.
but I guess you Don't want to Display it on Front-end (by Default)

You can extend **Category** model to do that.

if you have relative plugin / or / create your own plugin and in **Plugin.php** file define/override **boot** method and you can define something like this

```
use App;
use October\Rain\Database\Builder;

[...other code ...]

public function boot(){

    \RainLab\Blog\Models\Category::extend(function($model) {
        // App::runningInBackend() you can also use this one to make sure it will 
        // execute on frontend only
        if(!App::runningInBackend()) {
            $model::addGlobalScope('id', function(Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('id', '!=', 2);
            });            
        }
    });
}
```

Now, at the front-end side it will not show the categorie which is having **id => 2**

May be this can help you and If you need anything else please comment.
For plugin related details you can check here : https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration

Comment: How to add **multiple IDs**?

Comment: Done, I found a solution:)

Comment: This code hide the category, but also its posts on all pages of the site.
If someone wants to hide a category on only one page, then just use the appropriate check.

Answer (score 0):

Select **multiple IDs** of categories. Example.

```
use App;
use October\Rain\Database\Builder;

[...other code ...]

public function boot(){

    \RainLab\Blog\Models\Category::extend(function($model) {
        // App::runningInBackend() you can also use this one to make sure it will 
        // execute on frontend only
        if(!App::runningInBackend()) {
            $model::addGlobalScope('id', function(Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where([
                    ['id', '!=', 2],
                    ['id', '!=', 3],
                    ['id', '!=', 4]
                ]);
            });            
        }
    });
}
```

Now will not show the categories which is having **id => 2,3,4**

Comment: yes, now you have $builder, whatever conditions you like you can add them :)

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter version with **`whereNotIn`** eloquent method

`$builder->whereNotIn('id', [22, 32, 44]);`